# Custom Scaling on y-axis in matlab

Tags: matlab, scaling

I come across a strange scaling in y- axis in a IEEE journal paper.

From top to bottom

y_axis = [0.9999   0.9995 0.999   0.995 0.99 0.98   0.95   0.9 0.8 0.7 0.5 0.3 0.2 0.1 0.05 0.02  0.01  0.005   0.001 0.0005   0.0001].

The scaling is not logaritmic. The space between the ticks are not equal. Definitely, it is not linear. You can see the big numbers (0.9... 0.999) and very small numbers(0.0001... 0.1) in detail in only one y-axis. I don't know how to do in MATLAB. I googled it, but i could not find. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

The figure is the following code:

```
clear all
close all
set(0,'defaulttextinterpreter','latex')
P_tb = 1e-2;
Ntrial = 1e7;                  % # of Monte Carlo trials
jey=sqrt(-1);
omega_db = -15;                % sidelobe gain of main antenna
omega = db2pow(omega_db);      % omega in linear scale 
F_db = [-5 -2 0 2 5];
JNR_db = -5:20;
beta_db = 2;
F_lin = 10.^(0.1*F_db);
JNR = 10.^(0.1*JNR_db);
beta = 10.^(0.1*beta_db);
temp = cell (length(F_db),1);
P_b = zeros (length(JNR_db), length(F_db));
for ii = 1:length(F_db)
    SNR = JNR;
    x = sqrt(omega);
    F = F_lin(ii);
    P_b(:,ii) = 1 - 1./(F+1).*(1-marcumq(x.*sqrt(2.*SNR./(F+1)),sqrt(2.*SNR.*F./(F+1))))-F./(F+1).*marcumq(sqrt(2.*SNR.*F./(F+1)), x.*sqrt(2.*SNR./(F+1)));
    temp (ii) = {['$F=$' num2str(F_db(ii)) ' dB']};
end
figure,
h = plot(JNR_db, (P_b));
set(gca,'YTick',fliplr([0.9999 0.9995 0.999 0.995 0.99 0.98 0.95 0.9 0.8 0.7 0.5 0.3 0.2 0.1 0.05 0.02 0.01 0.005 0.001 0.0005 0.0001]))
set(gca,'YTickLabel',num2cell(fliplr([0.9999 0.9995 0.999 0.995 0.99 0.98 0.95 0.9 0.8 0.7 0.5 0.3 0.2 0.1 0.05 0.02 0.01 0.005 0.001 0.0005 0.0001])));
 grid on
```

Comment: Could you share a link to that paper, so we can see?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8w7adfzyckncv5z/1039418-fig-7-hires.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]This is the final solution that I found. Thank you very much. I did not know the sigmoid function. Below are the MATLAB codes for this puporse.

```
close all
clear all
%your desired y_ticks
y_axis = [0.9999 0.9995 0.999 0.995 0.99 0.98 0.95 0.9 0.8 0.7 0.5 0.3 0.2 0.1 0.05 0.02 0.01 0.005 0.001 0.0005 0.0001];
%order in increasing way
y_val = fliplr (y_axis);
% the Sigmoid function and its inverse
py_x = @(x) 0.5*erf(x*sqrt(pi/8)) + 0.5;
px_y = @(x) sqrt (8/pi)*erfinv (2*x - 1);

beta = 10^(0.1*-15);
F = 10^(0.1*-5);
JNR_db = -5:20;
SNR = 10.^(0.1.*JNR_db);
% my original data
P_b = @ (x) 1 - 1./(F+1).*(1-marcumq(x.*sqrt(2.*SNR./(F+1)),sqrt(2.*SNR.*F./(F+1))))-F./(F+1).*marcumq(sqrt(2.*SNR.*F./(F+1)), x.*sqrt(2.*SNR./(F+1)));
P_b1 = P_b(sqrt(beta));
% tranfrom it using inverse function
P_b2 = px_y(P_b1);
figure,
plot(JNR_db, P_b2);
grid on
ylim ([ px_y(0.0001) px_y(0.9999) ]);
% tranform the desired y_tick using inverse function
set(gca(), 'ytick', px_y (y_val));  
set (gca (), 'yticklabel', num2cell(y_val));
% % Sigmoid function verification
x_temp = linspace(-5,5,numel(y_axis));
figure
plot(x_temp, fliplr(y_axis), 'r');
hold on
plot (x_temp, py_x (x_temp), 'b' )
```

Answer (score 3):

In the figure posted by the OP, the tickmarks are not at all equally distributed. Also, the scale of the axis is rather the *inverse* of sigmoidal (see below). To really see what the authors of that paper did, we can skeletonize the figure

```
im = conv2(im, fspecial('gaussian', [5, 5], 2));
im = ~bwmorph(im < 2.5, 'skel', inf);
```

and obtain the exact positions `y_px` as in

```
y_px = flipud(find(im(:, 285) == 0));
y_px([1, 2, 3, 11, 15, 19, 28]) = [];
```

I am removing some of the detections which are from the trendlines or from the -10 tick mark label of the x-axis.

If you plot the y-tick labels `y_val` (flipping your `y_axis` into ascending order) as a function of those pixel positions `y_px`, you can confirm that the relationship is exactly sigmoidal as suggested by @chapjc. However, in order to produce similar plots, you may rather want to invert the formula and define a function

```
px_y = @(y) log(-y ./ (y - 1));
```

You can use this function then for plotting. The paper you refer to shows data in a range `x = -10 : 0.1 : 4`. Let's plot in this same range a sine function somewhere between 0.0001 and 0.9999. Note that we use our scaling function `px_y`, and then replace the y-tick positions *and* labels

```
plot(x, px_y(0.7 + sin(x) / 4));
set(gca(), 'ytick', px_y(y_val), 'yticklabel', num2cell(y_val));
```

resulting in something that should look like this

[image]

In summary, you can define a function `y_px` to transform your y-data, and then set the `ytick` and `yticklabel` properties of your axes. Whatever scale you choose for this approach, it is important to transform *both* the `ytick` values and all y-data with the same function.

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my problem. But I think you don't need to transform your x_axis. Basically, I understand from your answer as the following:
1. Keep the axis tick as y_axis = [0.0001 0.0005 ...];
2. Then transform your original y_data using the inverse function px_y = @(y) log(-y ./ (y - 1));
3. Then transform your y_axis using the inverse function.
4. Finally put the y_ticks on the transformed y_axis vector. You don't need to do anythink on x_axis. Thank you very much.

I will put the final MATLAB code below right now.

Comment: To be precise, you set the *transformed* values for `'ytick'`. I see you do that correctly in your own solution. Sorry about the confusion between `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 1):

To get an idea of this custom y-axis space, you can do `plot(linspace(-5,5,numel(y_axis)),fliplr(y_axis),'r')`.  This looked a lot like a dose curve, so plot an equation I found with `hold on; x=-5:0.01:5; plot(x,exp(x)./(1+exp(x)))`.  Here's what it looks like:

[image]

The form looks right.  There is probably a constant on one of the terms to tweak the shape. If you want to put your data in this space, apply this function (`yscFun = @(x) exp(x)./(1+exp(x))` or `yscFun = @(x) 1./(1+exp(-x))`).  Then set the tick labels to `y_axis` with `set(gca,'YTickLabel',num2cell(fliplr(y_axis)));` as suggested by nispio.

Comment: In general, this class of S-shaped functions are called "[sigmoids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)," if you want to explore other possible mappings.

Comment: Let me try that solution. I will tell you the results as soon as possible. Thanks for your answer..

Comment: @nispio - Thanks for the link.  user2948661 can try picking different sigmoids from your link and using them as suggested here.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It seems right when i plot the curve. But I did not understand exactly how to put my data in this space. Can you explain a little bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
set(gca,'YTick',fliplr([0.9999 0.9995 0.999 0.995 0.99 0.98 0.95 0.9 0.8 0.7 0.5 0.3 0.2 0.1 0.05 0.02 0.01 0.005 0.001 0.0005 0.0001]));
set(gca,'YTickLabel',num2cell(fliplr([0.9999 0.9995 0.999 0.995 0.99 0.98 0.95 0.9 0.8 0.7 0.5 0.3 0.2 0.1 0.05 0.02 0.01 0.005 0.001 0.0005 0.0001])));
```

Matlab wants the numbers to be in increasing order, so instead of reordering your numbers, I just invoked `fliplr` instead.

Comment: Using 'Ytick' just adds labels on y-axis. It does not scale it. I added the MATLAB code, you can check it. Thanks for your answer..

Comment: I see. I guess I misinterpreted what you mean by `the space between the ticks are not equal`. You actually want the graphical spacing of the ticks to be equal, even though the labels are increasing in a non-linear fashion.

Comment: @user2948661 - To scale your data too you need to apply a mapping to your data.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @chappjc: Your dose response curve looks like a reasonable transformation.  A raised cosine or root-raised-cosine could be good options as well (those are easily inverted).

Comment: yes you are right. Sorry for my bad explanation. I think when you run the code you see the point. There are some matlab functions on MATLAB fileexchange. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21864-breakplot. But it removes the white space from the one portion of the axis. But our situation is a little bit complicated.